# Contact form with spam-prevention

Tags: javascript, beginner, php, html, css

#### Idea

After a handfull of small javascript-projects, I also wanted to work a bit with php now. I decided to create a simple contact-form. Of course, I wanted it to be as spam-save as possible, so I used some of the ideas I found online (honeypott and some sort of CAPTCHA).

I realized the CAPTCHA-idea in the following way: Every time the user loads the contact-page a simple math-problem is created randomly and the user has to enter the correct solution to submit the form.

#### The Code

**Minimal working example**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

    <!-- Head -->
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Contact</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
    </head>

    <body>
        <main>
            <div style='margin:30px; margin-top: 50px'>
                <h2>Contact</h2>
                <div>
                    <form method="POST" action="send.php" class='input'>
                        <label>Your Name:</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Name" required/><br><br>

                        <label>Your Email:</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="myEmail" placeholder="E-Mail" required/><br><br>
                        
                        <!-- Honeypott -->
                        <input type="text" id="website" name="website"/>

                        <label>Message:</label><br>
                        <textarea rows="8" name="myMessage" style='width: 100%; resize: none; border: 1px solid Gray; border-radius: 4px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 10px 10px;' placeholder="Message" required></textarea><br><br>

                        <!-- For sending the simple math-exercise to the server -->
                        <input id='read' name='read' value='read' style='display: none;'/>

                        <label id='exercise'></label><br>
                        <input type='number' id='solution' name='solution' placeholder="Solution" required/>

                        <div style='display: inline-block; text-align: left;'>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="consent" name="consent" value="consent" required="">
                            <label>I agree with saving and sending this message according to the privacy policy.
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <input style='' type="submit" value="Send"/>    
                    </form>
                </div>                 
            </div> <!-- End main-div -->    
            <script>
                //Two random numbers for simple math-problem (spam-prevention)
                let array = ["one", "two", "three",
                            "four", "five", "six",
                            "seven", "eight", "nine",
                            "ten"];
                let item1 = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
                let item2 = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
                document.getElementById('exercise').innerHTML = item1 + " + " + item2 + " = ?";
                document.getElementById("read").value = item1 + " + " + item2;
            </script>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .input {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        margin: 10px 0;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: LightGray;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1001px) {
    .input {
        width: 30%;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        margin: 10px 0;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: LightGray;
    }
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: inline;
  border: 1px solid Gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: inline;
  border: 1px solid Gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=number] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: inline;
  border: 1px solid Gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#website {
  display: none;
}
```

**PHP-Code**

```php
<?php
    
    //Get simple math-problem (e.g. four + six)
    $str = $_REQUEST['read'];
    $first = strpos($str, " ");

    //Get first number (e.g. four)
    $substr1 = substr($str, 0, $first);

    //Get second number (e.g. six)
    $substr2 = substr($str, $first + 3, strlen($str) - $first - 3);
    $arr = array("zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten");

    /*
     * Convertring strings to numbers, e.g.
     * four -> 4
     * six  -> 6
     */
    $x = 0;
    $y = 0;

    for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        if(strcmp($substr1, $arr[$i]) == 0) {
            $x = $i;
            break;
        }
    }

    for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        if(strcmp($substr2, $arr[$i]) == 0) {
            $y = $i;
            break;
        }
    }

    $z = intval($_POST['solution']);

    //Did user enter right solution?
    if($z == ($x + $y)) {
        
        //Bot filled the honeypott-tree
        if(!empty($_POST['website'])) {
            echo "Something went wrong";
            die();
        }

        $userName = $_POST['myName'];
        $userEmail = $_POST['myEmail'];
        $userMessage = $_POST['myMessage'];

        //Did user enter a valid email-adress?
        if(!filter_var($userEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            echo "Something went wrong";
            die();
        }

        //Creating message
        $to = "mail@domain.com";
        $subject = "New Contact-form message";
        $body = "Content:";

        $body .= "\n\n Name: " . $userName;
        $body .= "\n\n Email: " . $userEmail;
        $body .= "\n\n Message: " . $userMessage;

        //Trying to send message
        if(mail($to, $subject, $body)){
            echo "Thank you for your message";
            die();
        } else{
            echo "Something went wrong";
            die();
        }
    }

    echo "Something went wrong";
?>
```

#### Question(s)

I am especially interested in suggestions to improve the php-code.

- Did I follow best-practices?
- Is anything in the code a really *bad* idea?

Another thing I am interested in is the safety of this approach. How can it improved further?

Of course all other suggestions are appreciated as well.

Comment: I fully support Certain's advice because putting a 24-inch-high fence around a swimming pool is only going to keep just-crawling toddlers from getting in -- the naughty teenagers next door will chuckle to themselves as they step right over it.  Here's my take on your 2-foot fence: https://3v4l.org/vMdJf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JS and front-end style**

- If you aren't going to reassign a variable, [always use `const` instead of `let`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6).
- Or, since this sounds like it's on a public facing website, if you wish to support ancient obsolete browsers that some users unfortunately still use (such as IE11), either write in ES5, or (recommended for anything more than a handful of lines) use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile your ES6+ source code to ES5 automatically for production.
- Better to only use `.innerHTML` when deliberately inserting or retrieving HTML markup. If you aren't dealing with HTML markup, using `textContent` is faster and safer. (setting `.innerHTML` with untrusted input is a security risk. The input happens to be trusted here, but it's better to get into the habit of only using `.innerHTML` when necessary)
- This is somewhat opinion-based, but I'd prefer to avoid creating elements with IDs, because the ID of the element will [implicitly become a global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables), and variable names that happen to be unexpectedly globally defined can be an easy source of bugs, especially in larger projects (unless you're using a [linter](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef) or Typescript to protect yourself). I'd use `class="foo"` instead of `id="foo"`.

**Security**

The random numbers are being generated on the front-end, and as a result are very simple for any interested abuser with a bit of understanding of JS to bypass. (Admittedly, this is unlikely for a small-time website, but it's still something that would be good to fix.) All they'd need to do would be to send a request with a pre-set `read` property of `one + one` and a solution of `2`, along with whatever spam messages they'd want to send, and they could send you 1000 of them.

I would recommend generating the random numbers on the *server*, and sending them to the client to verify in such a format that the random numbers could not be programatically extracted from payload easily.

If I were creating a home-spun solution rather than something tried-and-trusted like Recaptcha, I would have the client request an image from the server, have the server create the background image with [`imagecreatefrompng`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php), draw random text onto it with [`imagettftext`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php), save the text in a session variable, and send the image to the client for verification. It wouldn't be perfect, but it would dramatically raise the bar for successful abuse.