# Contact form with spam-prevention - follow-up

Tags: beginner, php, html, security

**Background**

The basics of this project are already covered [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/248695/contact-form-with-spam-prevention).

I received the suggestions to:

- not create the exercise with JavaScript.
- use pictures instead of plaintext.

I tried to implement the suggestions like this:

**The code**

Example-form:

```html
<form method="POST" action="../php/send.php" class='input'>
    <label>Your Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Name" required/><br><br>
    <label>Your Email:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="myEmail" placeholder="E-Mail" required/><br><br>
    
    <!-- Honeypott -->
    <input type="text" id="website" name="website"/>
    <label>Message:</label><br>
    <textarea rows="8" name="myMessage" style='width: 100%; resize: none; border: 1px solid Gray; border-radius: 4px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 10px 10px;' placeholder="Message" required></textarea><br><br>
    <input id='exerciseText' name='exerciseText', style='display: none;' value='
        <?php
        include '../php/randomExercise.php';
        $var = randText();
        echo $var;
        ?>'>
    </input>

    <label id='exercise'>
        
        <?php
        echo randExer($var);
        ?>
    </label><br>
    <input type='number' id='solution' name='solution' placeholder="Solution" required/>
    <div style='display: inline-block; text-align: left;'>
        <input type="checkbox" id="consent" name="consent" value="consent" required="">
        <label>I agree with saving and sending this message according to the privacy policy.
        </label>
    </div>
    <input style='' type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

`randomExercise.php`:

```php
<?php

    $encryptionPassword = "***";

    function randExer($rand) {

        //========================
        //Change for customization
        //========================

        //First of all:
        //Please change the $encryptionPassword above (16 chars)

        //Width of the created image
        $width = 200;

        //Height of the created image
        $height = 50;

        //RGB values for the text on the black image
        $textColorRed = 255;
        $textColorGreen = 255;
        $textColorBlue = 255;

        //RGB values of the random lines on the image
        $linesRed = 192;
        $linesGreen = 192;
        $linesBlue = 192;

        //Value between 1 and 5
        $fontSize = 5;  

        //Coordinates where the text starts
        $upperLeftCornerX = 18;
        $upperLeftCornerY = 18;

        //Text will be rotated by $angle-degrees
        $angle = 10;

        global $encryptionPassword;


        //=============================================
        //From here no changes needed for customization
        //=============================================

        $random = openssl_decrypt($rand,"AES-128-ECB", $encryptionPassword);
        
        //Creates a black picture
        $img = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

        //uses RGB-values to create a useable color
        $textColor = imagecolorallocate($img, $textColorRed, $textColorGreen, $textColorBlue);
        $linesColor = imagecolorallocate($img, $linesRed, $linesGreen, $linesBlue);

        //Adds text
        imagestring($img, $fontSize, $upperLeftCornerX, $upperLeftCornerY, $random . " = ?", $textColor);

        //Adds random lines to the images
        for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
            imagesetthickness($img, rand(1, 3));
            $x1 = rand(0, $width / 2);
            $y1 = rand(0, $height / 2);
            $x2 = $x1 + rand(0, $width / 2);
            $y2 = $y1 + rand(0, $height / 2);
            imageline($img, $x1, $x2, $x2, $y2, $linesColor);
        }

        $rotate = imagerotate($img, $angle, 0);

        //Attribution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22266437/13634030
        ob_start();
            imagejpeg($rotate);
            $contents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $imageData = base64_encode($contents);
        $src = 'data:'. mime_content_type($contents) . ';base64,' . $imageData;
        return '<img alt="" src="' . $src . '">';
    };

    function randText() {
        global $encryptionPassword;

        //Creating random (simple) math problem
        $arr = array("zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten");
        $item1 = $arr[array_rand($arr)];
        $item2 = $arr[array_rand($arr)];
        $random = $item1 . " + " . $item2;
        $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($random,"AES-128-ECB", $encryptionPassword);
        return $encrypted;
    }
?>
```

`send.php`

```php
<?php
    
    //Get simple math-problem (e.g. four + six)
    $str = openssl_decrypt($_REQUEST['exerciseText'], "AES-128-ECB", "***");
    
    $first = strpos($str, " ");

    //Get first number (e.g. four)
    $substr1 = substr($str, 0, $first);

    //Get second number (e.g. six)
    $substr2 = substr($str, $first + 3, strlen($str) - $first - 3);
    $arr = array("zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten");
    /*
     * Convertring strings to numbers, e.g.
     * four -> 4
     * six  -> 6
     */

    $x = 0;
    $y = 0;

    for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        if(strcmp($substr1, $arr[$i]) == 0) {
            $x = $i;
            break;
        }
    }

    for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        if(strcmp($substr2, $arr[$i]) == 0) {
            $y = $i;
            break;
        }
    }

    $z = intval($_POST['solution']);

    //Did user enter right solution?
    if($z == ($x + $y)) {
        
        //Bot filled the honeypott-tree
        if(!empty($_POST['website'])) {
            header("Location:/sites/messageError.html");
            die();
        }

        $userName = $_POST['myName'];
        $userEmail = $_POST['myEmail'];
        $userMessage = $_POST['myMessage'];

        //Did user enter a valid email-adress?
        if(!filter_var($userEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            header("Location:http:///sites/messageError.html");
            die();
        }

        //Creating message
        $to = "***";
        $subject = "New Contact-form message";
        $body = "Content:";

        $body .= "\n\n Name: " . $userName;
        $body .= "\n\n Email: " . $userEmail;
        $body .= "\n\n Message: " . $userMessage;

        //Trying to send message
        if(mail($to, $subject, $body)){
            header("/sites/message.html");
            die();
        } else{
            header("Location:/sites/messageError.html");
            die();
        }
    }

    header("Location:/sites/messageError.html");
?>
```

**Questions**

All suggestions are welcome, but I am especially interested in the security of this approach and how to further improve it.

---

Edit: I just created a [git-repository](https://codeberg.org/philippwilhelm/Simple_Captcha_System) and a working [demo](https://demo.philippwilhelm.eu/index.php). Maybe that's helpful for review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking about security, there are several issues:

- As a rule the attacker will go the easy way: send and analyze first request, remember `exerciseText` and `solution`, then send an unlimited number of requests from an unlimited number of devices. So, at least, you should use a timestamp to shorten the token's lifetime and tie it to a specific IP.
- In fact your encryption function makes no sense, because there are only 121 solutions and the attacker will notice very quickly that the `solution` always has the same value for same `exerciseText`. Therefore, you should at least append an UUID to your `$random` variable.
- Although, in your case the attacker can bypass your CAPTACHA just by sending `exerciseText=0&solution=0&...`. It's because there are no input validations and as a result your math verification comes down to `if(0 == (0 + 0))`. Moreover, on improperly configured servers it may lead to Full Path Disclosure.

As a last word I would like to say that it is very difficult to develop a spam free form without storing tokens into sessions or database. Well, your solution may be useful for learning and low traffic websites, but it's useless for popular ones.

### UPDATE

For a full PoC that bypasses CAPTCHA, check this cURL example:

```
curl -v https://demo.philippwilhelm.eu/send.php -d "myName=a&myEmail=a@b.c&myMessage=m&exerciseText=0&solution=0&consent=consent"
```

As a result your server returns following headers:

```
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Thu, 10 Sep 2020 16:17:50 GMT
* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache
< Upgrade: h2
< Connection: Upgrade
< Location: https://philippwilhelm.eu/sites/message.html
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Considering that server redirects the request to `/message.html` it means that message was successfully sent. So, let see what's wrong with your code (I removed your comments and added clarifications for each critical point):

```
# If attacker submits an empty/invalid `exerciseText` the `openssl_decrypt()` is not able to decrypt message and returns `FALSE` to `$str`
$str = openssl_decrypt($_REQUEST['exerciseText'], "AES-128-ECB", "***");

$first = strpos($str, " ");

# Both `$substr1` and `$substr2` will be assigned `FALSE` because both `substr()` are trying to extract a portion of string from a `FALSE` value
$substr1 = substr($str, 0, $first);
$substr2 = substr($str, $first + 3, strlen($str) - $first - 3);

$arr = array("zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten");

# Both `$x` and `$y` will remain equal to zero because in both cases `strcmp()` is not able to "convert strings to numbers"
$x = 0;
$y = 0;

for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    if(strcmp($substr1, $arr[$i]) == 0) {
        # The `$substr1` is `FALSE`, so `$i` is never assigned to `$x`
        $x = $i;
        break;
    }
}

for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    if(strcmp($substr2, $arr[$i]) == 0) {
        # The `$substr2` is `FALSE`, so `$i` is never assigned to `$y`
        $y = $i;
        break;
    }
}

# If attacker submits an empty `solution` the `$z` will be assigned the value `0` (zero)
$z = intval($_POST['solution']);

# Finally `$z=0; $x=0; $y=0` so the following expression will be always true
if($z == ($x + $y)) {
    ...
}
```

To avoid such vulnerabilities you must validate user input before before using it. So, let's rewrite the lines above to make sure that attacker won't be able to cheat on your validation:

```
# PHP has built-in functions for obtaining, validating and sanitizing submitted data, therefore in most cases you don't need to use superglobals
$solution = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'solution', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$exerciseText = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'exerciseText');

# Since in both cases `filter_input()` returns `FALSE` if something is wrong, you should not go further if any of these variables are invalid
if ($solution === false || $exerciseText === false) {
    die('bad request');
}

# Next you must make sure that `$exerciseText` has been successfully decrypted, otherwise exit your script
$str = openssl_decrypt($exerciseText, "AES-128-ECB", "***");
if (!$str) {
    die('cannot decrypt exercise');
}

# Define your numbers array
$arr = array("zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten");

# Since the `$str` contains several numbers separated by `+`, just split them and strip spaces
$words = array_map('trim', explode('+', $str)); //-> ["one", "two"]

# As the numbers match the indexes of `$arr`, you can find them using `array_intersect()`
$numbers = array_intersect($arr, $words); //-> [1=>"one", 2=>"two"]

# Make sure that it found two numbers
if (count($numbers) != 2) {
    die('hacking attempt');
}

# Sum up the indexes for the found numbers
$sum = array_sum(array_keys($numbers));

# Finally, check if user submitted a correct solution
if ($solution == $sum) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/248695/contact-form-with-spam-prevention#:~:text=save%20the%20text%20in%20a%20session%20variable

Comment: I don't really understand the third point. Could you explain where (and how) I should validate the input?

Comment: @PhilippWilhelm I updated my answer and added more details.

Answer (score 0):

## Security

The code basically attempts to create a [Client-side Request Forgery (CSRF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) token. Some frameworks like [laravel](https://laravel.com) provide this functionality [by default](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf). It may not be worth the effort of incorporating a framework if all you need is one feature but if there were others then you might consider it.

Generation of a CSRF token would be much simpler than creating an image an encoding it into string format.

As [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31683058/1575353) explains a CSRF token can be generated with various techniques. Hopefully the server running the code is using PHP 7.2 or later given [Supported versions](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php). Presuming that is the case [`random_bytes()`](https://php.net/random_bytes) to generate a cryptographically secure string of pseudo-random bytes and [`bin2hex()`](https://php.net/bin2hex) can be used to convert that string to a hexadecimal representation. As Victor's answer mentions a session can be used to store the token. A session can be started with [`session_start()`](https://php.net/session_start)

```
session_start();
$_SERVER['csrf_token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
```

Then that token can be included in the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="../php/send.php" class='input'>
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="<?=$_SERVER['csrf_token']?>" />
```

Then when the form is submitted, that value can be compared with the session value:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['csrf_token'] !== $_SERVER['csrf_token']) {
    header("Location:/sites/messageError.html");
}
```

This is especially important if PHP code should be executed before HTML or other output is emitted - e.g. sending headers.

## Review remarks

### PHP within HTML

Instead of this:

> ```
> <input id='exerciseText' name='exerciseText', style='display: none;' value='
>    <?php
>    include '../php/randomExercise.php';
>    $var = randText();
>    echo $var;
>    ?>'>
> ```

The external PHP file can be included at the top of the file:

```
<?php
include '../php/randomExercise.php';
?>
 <html> <!-- continue HTML below -->
```

Then in the form the function can be called using the shortcut syntax for `echo` - i.e. `<?= ?>`:

```
 <input id='exerciseText' name='exerciseText', style='display: none;' value='<?=randText()?>'>
```

### HTML

#### inline styles

Many elements have inline styles - e.g.

> ```
> <textarea rows="8" name="myMessage" style='width: 100%; resize: none; border: 1px solid Gray; border-radius: 4px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 10px 10px;' placeholder="Message" required></textarea><br><br>
> ```

Those styles could be moved to a `<style>` tag or external stylesheet so the markup won't contain so much styling.

p.s. `padding: 10px 10px;` can be condensed to `padding: 10px;`

#### email input type

There is an input for email address:

> ```
> <input type="text" name="myEmail" placeholder="E-Mail" required/><br><br>
> ```

The *type* attribute could be changed to [*email*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email) for validation purposes.

### PHP

#### Avoid `else` keyword when not necessary

In [this presentation about cleaning up code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GtB5DAfOWMQ) Rafael Dohms talks about many ways to keep code lean - like avoiding the `else` keyword. ([see the slides here](https://www.slideshare.net/rdohms/bettercode-phpbenelux212alternate/11-OC_1Only_one_indentation_level)).

It is wise to avoid the `else` keyword - especially when it isn't needed - e.g. when a previous block contains a `return` statement or call to `die()` - for example:

> ```
>    if(mail($to, $subject, $body)){
>        header("/sites/message.html");
>        die();
>    } else{
>        header("Location:/sites/messageError.html");
>        die();
>    }
> ```

p.s. should there be a `Location:` here?

> ```
>  header("/sites/message.html");
> ```

#### store encryption password in constant instead of global variable

In general usage of global variables is frowned upon for many reasons -e.g. because program state can be unpredictable, testing can be more difficult, etc. (refer to answers to [*Why is Global State so Evil?*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/148108/244085) for more information). A constant can be declared with [`declare()`](https://php.net/declare) or the [`const()`](https://php.net/const) keyword.

#### splitting strings

In *send.php* sub-string functions are used to split the string into words. The PHP function [`explode()`](https://php.net/explode) could be used with [`list()`](https://php.net/list) to assign to `$substr1` and `$substr2` in a single line.

#### generating number names

The method [`NumberFormatter::format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.format.php) class and the [`range()` function](https://php.net/range)
could be used to generate the number names in `$arr`.

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'en', NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
$arr = [];
foreach(range(0,10) as $number) {
    $arr[] = $fmt->format($number);
}
```

Bearing in mind that a beginner might be unfamiliar with such advanced techniques, the array could be generated with [`array_map()`](https://php.net/array_map):

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'en', NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT );
$arr = array_map($fmt->format, range(0, 10));
```

#### Searching for numbers by name

The PHP function [`array_search()`](https://php.net/array_search) could likely be used to eliminate the `for` loops to assign values for `$x` and `$y`.